# How to fix Gradle version with GCMPlugin cordova android

Tags: android, cordova

After add GCMPlugin into config.xml When hiting cordova build in terminal, I'm getting this message :

> Gradle version 2.10 is required. Current version is 2.2.1

I fix my gradle version in gradle-wrapper-properties and i run gradlew.bat.
Then i run cordova build, the message still appear in terminal.

How can i solve this error ?

Comment: What changes you have made in `gradle-wrapper-properties` could you post it.

Comment: distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip

Comment: Have you tried `Clean -> Rebuild` your project ? and also Do this `File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart...`.

Comment: I try and the error is display in terminal but in Android studio is not display.

Comment: Could you tell me what is your `Gradle Plugin` version. Which you have defined as `Class Path`.

Comment: thanks @jaydroider. I solve the problem by remove android platform and re-install.